# Multiple quotation marks in a SQL Server stored procedure for use with FREETEXT/FORMSOF

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameterized, formsof

I have been looking at this query snippet for awhile, thinking that I have the single quotes matched properly, but I keep getting blank result sets. Am I missing something here? I'm trying to find inflected versions of parametrized keyword phrases.

```
set @query = @query + 'AND (FREETEXT (ExampleTable.*, ''FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,"' + @keyword + '")'')'
```

Appreciate any insight. Hopefully it's just a dumb mistake on my part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx), the use of FORMSOF where you are using it (in the freetext_string parameter) seems not to be allowed. What makes you think this should work?

Comment: I must have just been staring at this too long. I was trying to squish in FORMSOF to search for inflectional variations, but FREETEXT already does that by default as the documentation points out. I just removed all of the FORMSOF language and went with the 'basic' FREETEXT search instead.